# Attempting to make a phrase generator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a button that upon clicking, fills an input box located right next to it with 3 random words and 2 preset words.

I have the 5 words with JQuery & Javascript going into `<p>` tags as of now, but I cannot figure out for my life how to get them into the input box.

Here's what I have so far for the JavaScript:
[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/fy1asfws/19/)

It's forcing me to put some of the code, so here is the short amount of HTML I have for it.

```
<h1>Shakespearean Insult Generator</h1>
    <div>
    <p id=word4></p>
    <p id=word1></p>
    <p id="word2"></p>
    <p id="word3"></p>
    <p id=word5></p>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="message" size="50" value="Thou">
    <button id="wordGen">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Anyway for the javascript part, i would use one function to retrieve the word, and a multidimensional array for the words. Your code right now is not reusable, because if someday you'll want do add another word, you'll have to define another function

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fy1asfws/23/

Comment: Your function structure should be different. As you can see, you have 3 almost identical functions which by name should return word (not index). I would do something like `function getWord(words) { 
    return words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
}` and then call it like `$('#word1').text(getword(words1));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your only issue is with how to set the value of a text input. Use jQuery's val method to set the value of the text input to the complete sentence that you have constructed. See:

http://api.jquery.com/val/

You should give the text input an id attribute (not necessary, as you could select by name), eg.

```
<input type="text" name="message" size="50" value="Thou" id="finalMessage">
```

and then something like this to select and set its value:

```
// construct the sentence
var finalMessage = 'Thou ' + words1[getWord1()] + ' ' + words2[getWord2()] + ' ' + words3[getWord3()];

// set the value of the text input to the sentence
$("#finalMessage").val(finalMessage);
```

As others have suggested you could also improve your method of selecting a random word to make it more reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#wordGen').click(function() {
    $('#word1').html("");
    $('#word2').html("");
    $('#word3').html("");
    $('#word1').append('<input value="' + words1[getWord1()] + '"></input>');
    $('#word2').append('<input value="' + words2[getWord2()] + '"></input>');
    $('#word3').append('<input value="' + words3[getWord3()] + '"></input>');
});
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/fy1asfws/24/

Comment: Thank you! This worked enough that I could edit it myself after this code :)

Comment: Great. Glad I could help :)

Comment: @BlakeBowling Please onsider accepting a valid answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, as I can see from the jsfiddle link, your question boils down to how to set the value property of an input field.

As you're using jQuery, this can be done by using the [val() method](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

In action for your generator:

```
$('input[name=message]').val(insultFunctionWord1() + insultFunctionWord2());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your three words and you need to put them in the `<input>`, then you need to use `$("#message").val()` to set the text for the input. Also, for this to work, you need to add `id="message"` to the `<input>` tag so that it becomes `<input type="text" id="message" name="message" size="50" value="Thou">`. For instance, your code might look like this:

```
val word1 = words1[getWord1()];
val word2 = words1[getWord2()];
val word3 = words1[getWord3()];
$('#word1').text(word1);
$('#word2').text(word2);
$('#word3').text(word3);
$("#message").val(word1 + " " + word2 + " " + word3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `javascript` alternative is just as concise as the solutions written in `jQuery` (and, arguably, could be abbreviated further):

```
function getWord(i) { 
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * words[(i-1)].length);
return words[(i-1)][randomNumber];
}

document.querySelector('#wordGen').onclick = function() {
var insult = getWord(1) + ' ' + getWord(2) + ' ' + getWord(3);
document.querySelector('input').value = insult;
}
```

Here is the full solution in plain vanilla `javascript`:

```js
var words = [

  ['artless',
  'bawdy',
  'beslubbering',
  'bootless',
  'churlish',
  'cockered',
  'clouted',
  'craven',
  'currish',
  'dankish',
  'dissembling',
  'droning',
  'errant',
  'fawning',
  'fobbing',
  'froward',
  'frothy',
  'gleeking',
  'goatish',
  'gorbellied',
  'impertinent',
  'infectious',
  'jarring',
  'loggerheaded',
  'lumpish',
  'mammering',
  'mangled',
  'mewling',
  'paunchy',
  'pribbling',
  'puking',
  'puny',
  'qualling',
  'rank',
  'reeky',
  'roguish',
  'ruttish',
  'saucy',
  'spleeny',
  'spongy',
  'surly',
  'tottering',
  'unmuzzled',
  'vain',
  'venomed',
  'villainous',
  'warped',
  'wayward',
  'weedy',
  'yeasty',
  ],

  ['base-court',
  'bat-fowling',
  'beef-witted',
  'beetle-headed',
  'boil-brained',
  'clapper-clawed',
  'clay-brained',
  'common-kissing',
  'crook-pated',
  'dismal-dreaming',
  'dizzy-eyed',
  'doghearted',
  'dread-bolted',
  'earth-vexing',
  'elf-skinned',
  'fat-kidneyed',
  'fen-sucked',
  'flap-mouthed',
  'fly-bitten',
  'folly-fallen',
  'fool-born',
  'full-gorged',
  'guts-griping',
  'half-faced',
  'hasty-witted',
  'hedge-born',
  'hell-hated',
  'idle-headed',
  'ill-breeding',
  'ill-nurtured',
  'knotty-pated',
  'milk-livered',
  'motley-minded',
  'onion-eyed',
  'plume-plucked',
  'pottle-deep',
  'pox-marked',
  'reeling-ripe',
  'rough-hewn',
  'rude-growing',
  'rump-fed',
  'shard-borne',
  'sheep-biting',
  'spur-galled',
  'swag-bellied',
  'tardy-gaited',
  'tickle-brained',
  'toad-spotted',
  'unchin-snouted',
  'weather-bitten',
  ],

  ['apple-john',
  'baggage',
  'barnacle',
  'bladder',
  'boar-pig',
  'bugbear',
  'bum-bailey',
  'canker-blossom',
  'clack-dish',
  'clotpole',
  'coxcomb',
  'codpiece',
  'death-token',
  'dewberry',
  'flap-dragon',
  'flax-wench',
  'flirt-gill',
  'foot-licker',
  'fustilarian',
  'giglet',
  'gudgeon',
  'haggard',
  'harpy',
  'hedge-pig',
  'horn-beast',
  'hugger-mugger',
  'joithead',
  'lewdster',
  'lout',
  'maggot-pie',
  'malt-worm',
  'mammet',
  'measle',
  'minnow',
  'miscreant',
  'moldwarp',
  'mumble-news',
  'nut-hook',
  'pigeon-egg',
  'pignut',
  'puttock',
  'pumpion',
  'ratsbane',
  'scut',
  'skainsmate',
  'strumpet',
  'varlot',
  'vassal',
  'whey-face',
  'wagtail',
  ]

  ];

function getWord(i) { 
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * words[(i-1)].length);
    return words[(i-1)][randomNumber];
}

document.querySelector('#wordGen').onclick = function() {
var insult = getWord(1) + ' ' + getWord(2) + ' ' + getWord(3);
document.querySelector('input').value = insult;
}
```

```css
button {
background-image: url( 'https://media.giphy.com/media/URZcG7uLd9h4s/giphy.gif' );
    background-size: 100px 130px;
    height: 250;  
    width: 250;
    //background-size: auto;
    font: 15px Verdana, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font: 35px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h1>Shakespearean Insult Generator</h1>
<input type="text" size="30" />
<button id="wordGen">Click Me!</button>
```